# Unable to get reproducible results with Keras using random seed

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am having problems in ensuring reproducibility of my Python script using Keras and random seeds. I have followed the guidelines provided [here](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development), but everytime I run the scripts I get different results. Now, the structure of my code could be the issue here.
I have a script which defines two functions, one doing a grid search of hyperparameters, and one fitting the models with the optimized values:

```
<SCRIPT STRUCTURE>:

seed_value=123
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)
import random
random.seed(seed_value)
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(seed_value)
import tensorflow
tensorflow.random.set_seed(seed_value)

def hyperparameter_tuning(data):
    "here the hyperparameters are selected"
    import os, numpy, tensorflow        
    ...
    return param1, param2, param3, rmse


def model_fit(data, param1, param2, param3):
    "here the optimized model is fit"
    import os, numpy, tensorflow
    ...
    return rmse


dataset=pd.read_csv(data)
hyperparameter_tuning(dataset)
model_fit(dataset, param1, param2, param3)
```

If I run the full script and then check the output I notice that I get different results in terms of model performance, despite the model specification being absolutely identical and the dataset being exactly the same. Everything from splitting the dataset to scaling it is also the same in both functions. I am not sure what is going on here.

Could it be that I am setting the seed at the beginning of the script while I should set it *inside* the function fitting the models?

Or could it be that I am importing the os, numpy, and tensorflow modules at the beginning and then reimporting them within each function such that the seed is somehow reset?

One final note: running each function twice yields the same rmse *within* the same function, but the rmses are different *between* functions. However, as I mentioned, the model specs and datasets  are copypasted in both functions.